# How to keep Webkit zooming fixed?

Tags: google-chrome, safari, webkit, zooming

I am having a problem related to Webkit.  The site I am testing is here:

http://development.mminc.co/ironsharpensiron/templates/ironsharpensiron/index-template1-051611.html

I am trying to keep the width/height between elements the same in the carousel on the right.
Every other browser zooms in/out fine and thus the carousel works fine, but on Webkit it decides to play by its own rules and the carousel breaks.  Has anybody experienced similar issues and if so have you found a solution?  Thank you.